# Setting defaultDate on DateTimePicker, with use of functions from dtp on event firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I'm using [Bootstrap Datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) to have a calendar on my page and select days and hours.

I'm setting up this way:

```
var $dtp = $("#datetimepicker1");
$(function () {
    $dtp.datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:00',
        locale: 'pt',
        defaultDate: d,
        minDate: dMin,
        maxDate: dMax
    });
});
```

And I have trigger `"dp.change"`:

```
$dtp.on("dp.change", function(e) { 
    d = $dtp.data("DateTimePicker").date().toDate();
});
```

`dMin`, `dMax` and `d` are Date Objects:

```
var d = new Date(); //actual Date
var dMin = new Date(2012, 0, 1, 0);
var dMax = new Date(); dMax.setDate(dMax.getDate()+2); dMax.setHours(0); //more 2 days
```

Well, I need to set up `defaultDate`, because sometimes `d` are changed and it's not the current date, but another date between `dMin` and `dMax`.

The problem is that, no matter if `d` is current or not, with `defaultDate` on the initializing setup of datetimepicker, the calendar doesn't work.

Inspecting the error, on console, I conclude that `$dtp.data("DateTimePicker")` is `undefined`, when first `"dp.change"` occurs, but only when I have `defaultDate` on initializing setup.

I'm having some problems on solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check if `$dtp.data("DateTimePicker")` is not `undefined` using something like `if( $dtp.data("DateTimePicker") )` inside your [`dp.change`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange) listner. You can also use event parameter, as the [docs](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange) says:

> Fired when the date is changed.
>
> Parameters:
>
> ```
> e = {
>     date, //date the picker changed to. Type: moment object (clone)
>     oldDate //previous date. Type: moment object (clone) or false in the event of a null
> }
> ```

Here a live sample:

```js
var d = new Date(); //actual Date
var dMin = new Date(2012, 0, 1, 0);
var dMax = new Date();
dMax.setDate(dMax.getDate()+2);
dMax.setHours(0); //more 2 days

var $dtp = $("#datetimepicker1");
$(function () {
    $dtp.datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:00',
        locale: 'pt',
        defaultDate: d,
        minDate: dMin,
        maxDate: dMax
    });
});

$dtp.on("dp.change", function(e) {
    // Solution 1: simply check for undefined
    //if( $dtp && $dtp.data("DateTimePicker") ) d = $dtp.data("DateTimePicker").date().toDate();
    if( e.date ){
        d = e.date.toDate();
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.2/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class='col-sm-6'>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id="datetimepicker1">
      <input type='text' class="form-control" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Moreover, since the component uses [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/), you can init `d`, `dMin` and `dMax` like this:

```js
var d = moment(); //actual Date
var dMin = moment([2012, 0, 1]);
var dMax = moment().add(2, 'days').startOf('day');
```

See [`moment()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/now/), [`moment(Number[])`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/array/), [`add()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) and [`startOf()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) for further reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works.
Something so simple and I was doing a major problem.
And I will consider use momentjs. I was using Date Object, because I start to work with that on my page for some time and I need to integrate datetimepicker with the existent code...